# JS show div / notification till link in it is clicked

Tags: javascript, click, show

I'm creating a website where the user gets an tutorial to learn about the site.
First, I check if the tutorial was already shown with:

```
function check_tutorial(tutorial_name) {
    if(localStorage.getItem('tutorial_' + tutorial_name) == null){
        show_tutorial(tutorial_name);
        localStorage.setItem('tutorial_' + tutorial_name, 'true');
    }
};
```

I can call the function via onClick="check_tutorial();" for example or on Document load via:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    check_tutorial(filename);
});
```

To get the filename automatically and just edit my intro.js.

```
function show_tutorial(tutorial_name) {
    if(tutorial_name === "index.php"){
        [...]
        [...]
    }
}
```

Now I want some div-containers to notify the user about changes or give him tips for pending settings.
Here, I just want to show it as long as the user clicked on it / clicked on the link in the notify-container.

For example on the index.php a container says that the user have to set settings in settings.php

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="#" class="alert-link">Alert Link</a>.
</div>
```

I want to show the container until:
1. The user clicks on the link in the container
2. The user clicks dismiss 
3. The user was already on settings.php

I thought about to set a localStorage in settings.php and set it to true.
And just show the container 
`if localStorage('settings.php') == null`

Is it the right way or is there an other and better way for me to display tutorials and notifications?

https://plnkr.co/edit/qLBBRIuWVlsmAdo7jPP1

Comment: better make a plunker

Comment: What is a plunker? Can you explain? :-)

Comment: check this https://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/qLBBRIuWVlsmAdo7jPP1

Run it two times and thats my method I currently use. Is there andy better way?

Comment: I didn't get you